# Jest - expect throw message test

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to write a test to test if an error has thrown

```
exports.handler = async data => {
  try {
      throw new Error("Invalid Data")
    };
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
};
```

I wrote a test which is working as expected

```
it("Throw Error Invalid Data", async () => {
    try {
       await function.handler({});
    } catch (err) {
      expect(err).toEqual(new Error("Invalid Data"));
    }
})
```

How do avoid using try/catch block in the test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`.rejects`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async#rejects) helper:

```
it("Throw Error Invalid Data", () => {
  return expect(handler({})).rejects.toEqual(new Error("Invalid Data"));
});
```

Or with an async function:

```
it("Throw Error Invalid Data", async () => {
  await expect(handler({})).rejects.toEqual(new Error("Invalid Data"));
});
```

Comment: Why is it `.rejects` ?

Comment: Because `async` functions always return a `Promise` and thus behave identical to them.

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back that's just [how the Jest team decided to call that API](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/968ddc416ae52f15e15ed1e64b0196f44c3dabde/packages/expect/src/index.js#L115).

Answer (score 1):

Like [this](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1700#issuecomment-386019524):

```
await expect(handler({})).rejects.toThrow(new Error("Invalid Data"));
```